# Xamarin custom controls, how do I add properties to display in the Xcode panel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I want to implement custom controls, but the official case is too limited, I can not know more. What I want to know now is that I want to add an attribute to my control, such as Title, which must be free to fill in the Xcode control properties panel.

My current learning document: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/user-interface/custom-controls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted when you also asked [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93252/xamarin-mac-custom-controls-how-do-i-add-properties-to-display-in-the-xcode-panel#latest):

> So if you are referring to:
>
> https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_walkthrough/#Adding_Design-Time_Properties
>
> (since it contains UIImage), that is discussing Xamarin Studio's built
>   in iOS designer. Xamarin.Mac does not have such a feature.
>
> The Xcode way of doing this is via IBInspectable / IBDesignable
>
> http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/
>
> however, Xcode / Xamarin.Mac does not have support for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a very sad news for me. Why not join us if possible?